# Send values to Javascript function to display in element

Tags: javascript, overlay, href

I have this

```
<a href='#?title=sample&url=sample.com'></a>
```

on the same page I put

```
$title = $_GET['title'];
$url = $_GET['url'];
```

but it doesn't passes the values.
what's wrong with the code?
help please!

NOTE:
I wanted not to reload the page that's why i put # because at the later part I will call a javascript function onclick

here's the function call onclick

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function overlay() {
el = document.getElementById("overlay");
el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
</script>
```

where the element "overlay" must contain the value of

```
$title = $_GET['title'];
$url = $_GET['url'];
```

Comment: Hi Ivory, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to remove the hash (#) from your URL. If you need the hash tag in your URL, it must at the end of the URL:

```
mydomain.com?id=1#tag
```

If you place the hash before the querystrings like you have, you are basically telling the browser to find an element/target called "?title=sample&url=sample.com", which it probably won't like.

**For your updated question:**

I think you are better off using the link to call your javascript function, instead of adding querystring values to you URL like you have. For PHP to be able to get these values, the page would have to reload/send request to the server. If you do not want the page to reload, I suggest you change your link to this:

```
<a onclick="overlay('This is the title','www.domain.com')">
```

and then have a function:

```
function overlay(theTitle, theURL) {
  el = document.getElementById("overlay");
  el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
  el.innerHTML = theTitle+'<br>'+theURL;
}
```

This means you can get the values you wanted without refreshing the page.

Comment: yeah your right with your answer for the updated question @PaparazzoKid , the problem why i didn't used that is because i dont know how to pass that var from javascript back to html. heres my code when javascript function is call <script language="JavaScript">
function overlay() {
 el = document.getElementById("overlay");
 el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
</script>

Comment: @ivory-santos: I'm not sure I understand that. Did you want to show the 'Title' and 'URL' in your overlay HTML?

Comment: the function first call a div, making it visible on screen. but my problem is... how can i throw the value of title and url inside the div.

Comment: @ivory-santos: I have update my answer again. Notice the extra line: **el.innerHTML**.

Comment: that's not work. I did this                          <a href onclick='overlay(this)'data-title='title'>                  
 function overlay(e)                                           
{var readers = e.getAttribute('data-title');
el = document.getElementById("overlay-title");
el.innerHTML = readers;}

Comment: by the way, still a big thank you for you @ PaparazzoKid , I've got an idea on your help!

Comment: @ivory-santos: If my answer helped you, please click the green tick to accept it. This closes the question so others don't need to spend time answering and already answered question. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

The `#` tells the browser that you're trying to go to an anchor on the page so it won't make another HTTP request to the server.

If you want to make the request to the server, you have to remove the `#` symbol and add the URL to the page:

```
<a href="mypage.php?title=sample&url=sample.com">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your URL only includes a fragment identifier (the final part of a URL which starts with a `#` character).

This allows you to link to a specific part of a page (identified by an element with an id attribute that matches the fragment identifier, or by an anchor element with a matching name) and is handled entirely client side - it isn't sent to the server.

**Remove the `#` character from the URI or place it *after* the query string.**

(Also note that your HTML is invalid, `&` indicates the start of a character reference and should be represented as `&amp;` if you want one to appear as data)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the # from a href.
try instead `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` which holds (this) script name

```
print('<a href='.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'?title=SAMPLE&url=SAMPLE.COM'>Link</a>')
```

Comment: the page reload @GeoPhoenix , i dont want the page to reload because my onclick function will disappear